# If $c \leq n-(n+1) \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ for $n>1$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a sequence $\{a_n\}$ with all positive terms and we know that $\{n*an\}$ converge and if $c>0$ $c \leq n-(n+1) \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ for $n>1$ how can i show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ converge

I did

$0\leq n-(n+1)\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq\frac{n}{n+1}$

and applying limit to both sides
$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1
$

So $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq 1$ and then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ converges
but i dont know because i think im asumming that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ has limit and i think this is wrong

Comment: That is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe's_test.

Answer (score 2):

$$c \cdot (\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} c\cdot a_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}  ka_k -(k+1)a_{k+1}=a_1 - (n+1)a_{n+1} \leq a_1 $$
The partial sums are bounded,therefore the sum converges.
Note that we only used the fact the $ a_k \geq 0 ,$ and not that $(a_k)_{k \in N}$ converges.

Comment: +1. Nice answer.